# Prove heteroclinic connection between fixed points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider an autonomous system of the plane $(\dot{x}, \dot{y}) = X(x,y)$, given by
$$
\begin{cases}
     \dot{x} = 2x-x^3-3xy^2 \\ \dot{y} = y-y^3-x^2y
\end{cases}
$$
Our goal is to prove that there exists a fixed point in the interior of the 1st quadrant that is heteroclinically connected with the rest of the fixed points in this quadrant.

We have found the following equilibrium points:

- $(0,0)$, a repeller node,
- $(0,1)$, an attractor node,
- $(\sqrt{2},0)$, an attractor node, and
- $(\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2)$, a saddle point;

therefore, we ought to prove that $(\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2)$ is heteroclinically connected to every other fixed point in the list.

Our approach to the problem has been to use the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem. First of all, we have found a positively invariant compact set $K = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 | 0 \leq x \leq \sqrt{2}/2, 0 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\} \cup \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 | \sqrt{2}/2 \leq x \leq \sqrt{2}, 0 \leq x^2 + 3y^2 \leq 2\}$. Then, by the Poincaré-Bendixson theorem, the $\omega$-limit set of $(\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2)$ must be one of the following:

- A periodic orbit, which we rule out, as a periodic orbit must wrap a fixed point, and, since every fixed point is in $\partial K$ and $K$ is positively invariant, this cannot be satisfied.
- A fixed point, which we cannot find the way to prove impossible.
- An heteroclinic connection of fixed points, which is the one we want to prove right.

Therefore, the main question relating to the problem is how can we prove that $\omega (\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2)$ cannot be a fixed point, in order to find the desired heteroclinic connection. Thanks in advance for your help and comments.

Comment: Please check your work. The stationary point $(\sqrt{2}/2,\sqrt{2}/2)$ is not an attratcor. Also, a phase plot will give you more insight. You can make one with any CAS.

Comment: Correct, thanks for the insight.

Comment: Consider also the $\alpha$ limit set of this point,